# How to use Mule Expression Language for dynamic spring property injection

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el

```
<set-variable variableName="template" value="#[payload.templatePath]" doc:name="Template Path"/>
<custom-transformer class="com.comviva.mfs.eig.transformers.generic.MapUtil" doc:name="Map">
<spring:property name="sessionBean" ref="SessionBean"/>
<spring:property name="fixedTemplatePath" value="#[flowVars['template']]"/>
```

OR In both cases I want the value of the map to be replaced dynamically while sending the data as the key templatePath contains dynamic value and I want that to get picked from the payload that is of Map type

```
<custom-transformer class="com.comviva.mfs.eig.transformers.generic.MapUtil" doc:name="Map">
<spring:property name="sessionBean" ref="SessionBean"/>
<spring:property name="fixedTemplatePath" value="#[payload.templatePath]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring properties are not  interpreted by the MEL. As it is provided as setter injection which is invoked during instantiation the value of payload or a flow/session var will not be available.

You can change the transformer code to read the value from the payload within the transformation code itself as payload will be available from 'Object src' param.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan I am clear about spring injection now, just wanted to ask  isn't there any other way of doing this without code change in the transformer